# Troubleshooting hung NFS drive

Tags: macos, mount, nfs

I have mounted a NFS drive through /etc/fstab on an Mac OS X computer, and it seems to be hung or stuck.  When I try `cd /path/to/mounted/drive`, the command sticks and never completes. What commands can I use to get more information about the drive? Is there a command I can use to detect when a mounted drive is in a bad state?